# How can I delete a row in a datagrid view and update the MySQL database on a delete button click event?

Tags: c#, mysql

So far I have managed to delete the record from the datagrid view on a button click event, but the problem is that the database is not changing.

I'm using `datagrid_booktitles.Rows.RemoveAt(oneCell.RowIndex);` to remove the row from the datagrid and `cmd = new MySqlCommand("DELETE FROM`sarasavi_library`.`book_title`WHERE`book_number`= 'book_number';");` to remove it from the database.

Below is my full code for the delete button click event:

```
private void btn_delete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewCell oneCell in datagrid_booktitles.SelectedCells)
        {
            if (oneCell.Selected)
                datagrid_booktitles.Rows.RemoveAt(oneCell.RowIndex);

            cmd = new MySqlCommand("DELETE FROM `sarasavi_library`.`book_title` WHERE `book_number`= 'book_number';");
        }
    }
```

Am I doing something wrong here? I have a feeling that there's a problem with my MySQL command, But I can't think of another way. Any ideas?

Comment: Shoudnt you have a executequery in there?

Comment: I tried using `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` but still it didn't delete the record from database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think I found the answer for this. I have assigned the datagrid value to a string and used it in the database query.

```
foreach (DataGridViewCell oneCell in datagrid_booktitles.SelectedCells)
{
   if (oneCell.Selected == false) continue;

   string i = datagrid_booktitles.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
   datagrid_booktitles.Rows.RemoveAt(oneCell.RowIndex);
   string query = "DELETE FROM `sarasavi_library`.`book_title` WHERE `book_number`='" + i +"'";

   using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Constring"].ToString()))
   {
      using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn))
      {
         conn.Open();
         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need create and provide instance of `MySqlConnection` for executing commands on database.

```
private void btn_delete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewCell oneCell in datagrid_booktitles.SelectedCells)
    {
        if (oneCell.Selected == false) continue;

        datagrid_booktitles.Rows.RemoveAt(oneCell.RowIndex);
        string query = 
            "DELETE FROM `sarasavi_library`.`book_title` WHERE `book_number`='book_number'"

        using(var conn = new MySqlConnection("yourConnectionString"))
        {
            using(var command = new MySqlCommand(query, conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Before executing query you need to  open a connection `conn.Open();`

Comment: Now row gets deleted from the gridview but not from the database.

Comment: With information your provided - solution will sure that your query is executed against database. You need check does your query is correct. Does `WHERE` clause filter right rows? Are your sure then comparison `'book_number'='book_number'` is correct, may be you need to provide some value for `book_number`

Answer (score 1):

Try This for delete selected row of datagridview from database.

```
SqlConnection con=new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SqlExpress;Initial      Catalog=DatabaseName;Integrated Security=True"); 

 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count > 1 && dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index != dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1)

 {

 delcmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM table_Name WHERE Column_Name=" + dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString() + "";

                con.Open();

                delcmd.Connection = con;

                delcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                con.Close();
                dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index);

                MessageBox.Show("Row has been Deleted");


            }
```

Comment: it gives me Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'A0005' error [image](http://joxi.ru/ZrJOGQZf1jGVEm.jpg)